# How to add certificate to drupal_http_request()?

Tags: 7, http-request

I am currently setting up a payment method in my Drupal 7 site and following the API documentation for the service I could use this cURL command for testing purposes:

```
$ curl -s -S -i --cert
./Swish_Merchant_TestCertificate_1231181189.p12:swish --cert-type p12 --
cacert ./Swish_TLS_RootCA.pem --tlsv1.1 --header "Content-Type:
application/json"
https://mss.cpc.getswish.net/swish-cpcapi/api/v1/paymentrequests --data
'{ "payeePaymentReference" : "0123456789", "callbackUrl" :
"https://myfakehost.se/swishcallback.cfm", "payerAlias" : "4671234768",
"payeeAlias" : "1231181189", "amount" : "100", "currency" : "SEK",
"message" : "Kingston USB Flash Drive 8 GB" }'
```

But since I am developing this function in Drupal 7 I want to use drupal_http_request instead. But I am confused about how to include the certificates used in the cURL command. Anyone?

EDITED:
After the suggestion below I added a context parameter. I still get "connection refused by destination". Is there anything more I should do? This is how my function looks so far:

```
function create_payment_request(){
  // Send payment request to Swish API
  $headers =  array('Content-Type'=>'application/JSON' );
  $url = "https://mss.cpc.getswish.net/swish-cpcapi/api/v1/paymentrequests";

  $context = stream_context_create([ 'ssl' => [
  'local_cert'        => '/mypathtocertificates/TestCertificate_123456789.pem',
  'passphrase'        => 'pass' ]]);

  $json = '{
  "payeePaymentReference": "0123456789",
  "callbackUrl: "/swish_callback",
  "payerAlias": "4671234768",
  "payeeAlias: "1231181189",
  "amount": "100",
  "currency": "SEK",
  "message": "testo 925"
}
';

  $options=array(
      'headers'=>$headers,
      'context' => $context,
      'method'=>'POST',
      'data'=>$json,
    );

    $result=drupal_http_request($url, $options);
    dpm($result);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply a `context` parameter in the options for `drupal_http_request`. The value is a stream context created using the PHP function [stream_context_create](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php).

There are a lot of possible parameters so you may have to hunt through the [parameter list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.php) to find the ones you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have edited my question. There is still something wrong though, the destination refuses to connect.

Comment: Not an expert on this but might you need a cacert entry as well?

Comment: That took me one step further. Now the status is "connecting", but I still get an error: "Error initializing socket". But thanks a lot, I will contact this payment provider directly to figure out the rest. Thanks a lot for your input. Correct answer since the context parameter is just what was missing.